# How can I apply vertical spacing between elements in a ZStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In this code, I have a semi-transparent header at the top of the view that blurs the views in a ScrollView.

I want to place the ScrollView under the header so you can see it blurred as it passes under the HeaderView(). I have done this using 'ZStack(alignment: .top)'. However the top of the ScrollView is already being covered by the HeaderView() which is not what I want.

Anytime I have managed to separate the HeaderView() from the ScrollView (for example using an offset), the transparency effect is lost.

Here is the code, I have given the views borders. The yellow border should be touching the blue border (HeaderView()). However, you can only see the yellow border if you scroll up because it is being covered by the blue border of the HeaderView()

Here is my code for a reproducible example:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    
                    ScrollView {
                        
                        VStack {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.red)
                                .frame(width: 430, height: 250)
                            
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.blue)
                                .frame(width: 430, height: 250)
                            
                            
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.orange)
                                .frame(width: 430, height: 250)
                            
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.green)
                                .frame(width: 430, height: 250)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .border(.yellow)
                    }
                                                            
                    HeaderView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "fanblades.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.mint)
                .font(.system(size: 30))
            
            Spacer()
        }
            .background(VisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)).ignoresSafeArea())
            .border(.blue)
    }
}

struct VisualEffectView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var effect: UIVisualEffect?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        UIVisualEffectView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        uiView.effect = effect
    }
}
```

Here is what it looks like: (the header and the stack containing circles should not overlap when initialised)

[image: How it looks]

Here is how I need it to look:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add more padding to the top of the `VStack` inside the `ScrollView`:

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        // contents as before
    }
    .padding()
    .border(.yellow)
    .padding(.top, 40) // <-- HERE
}
```

[image: BlurZone]